# dd($var) is working and showing but{{$var}} is giving undefined object Laravel5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I get the data that I want to show out of a `foreach` loop like this

```
 @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
{{dd($notification->data)}}
{{--{{dd($notification->data['thread']['id'])}}--}}
{{--{{dd($notification->data['thread']['subject'])}}--}}
{{--{{dd($notification->data['user']['name'])}}--}}
@endforeach
```

All the `dd` show the data there suppose to show whit out any errors but when I for loop like this.

```
        @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                            <a href="{{ropgpute('thread.show',$notification->data['thread']['id'])}}">
                                {{$notification->data['user']['name']}} commented on <strong> {{$notification->data['thread']['subject']}}</strong>
                            </a>
        @endforeach
```

its gives an error back error:

```
  Undefined index: thread (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel Projects\Forum\resources\views\layouts\partials\navbar.blade.php)
```

Note also `user` is undefined

I dont understand why the `dd` works fine and shows the data but the normal `foreach` loop whit out the data is not showing anything and returning an undefined index thread

the `{{dd($notification->data)}}` output

```
 array:2 [▼
"thread" => array:8 [▼
"id" => 1
"subject" => "JSUpdated Updated Updated"
"thread" => "eaeaweaweaewaeawawneaklfnd/waldfwa.fwa"
"type" => "Question Updated"
"created_at" => "2019-03-14 15:34:28"
"updated_at" => "2019-03-14 15:34:38"
"user_id" => 1
"solution" => 2
 ]
"user" => array:6 [▼
"id" => 1
"name" => "johndoe"
"email" => "johndoe@example.com"
"email_verified_at" => null
"created_at" => "2019-03-14 15:34:15"
"updated_at" => "2019-03-14 15:34:15"
]
]
```

Comment: Could you post the `dd` of `$notification->data`?

Comment: The problem with `dd` is that it will kill the application, so if the problem is on the second iteration of the `foreach`, you will not be able to se it. Try changing to `var_dump($notification->data)` and see if all the `$notification` have the requested `fields`

Comment: Will you always return that array of 2 or can you have more?

Comment: yes only that array of 2

Comment: i am having the same error, its working fine at one page, but when loaded on another its giving fault

Answer (score 0):

I notice value of `$notification->data['thread']` is `"eaeaweaweaewaeawawneaklfnd/waldfwa.fwa"`. This is a string .Then in your code you try to `$notification->data['thread']['id']` . This mean you try to get some value of array but actually your data is string.

Comment: So how would you get them out then in that case?

Answer (score 0):

`dd => dump and die`. so if you have included in the loop, it will dump the value for first and interrupt the application from continuing.